Validating Model Setup for Differential Abundance Analysis Using ANCOM-BC in R
I am conducting an analysis on microbiota data from a study involving 55 women, categorized by pregnancy status and BMI (lean vs. obese). The goal is to explore the differential abundance of microbiota across different trimesters and BMI categories using the Bioconductor ANCOM-BC package.
Data Overview:

Trimesters: Ordered factor (Preconceptional, First, Second, Third).
BMI: Categorical factor (Lean, Obese).
Subject: unique ID per subject

Current Modeling Approach:
I've modeled the interaction between trimester and BMI using a composite factor (TRIBMI) and am using the following ANCOM-BC setup. Also, following the structure used in the ANCOM-BC package examples, I initially attempted to model random slopes for Trimester within subjects (using (Trimester | subject)), but encountered issues due to having fewer observations (n=68) than the number of random effects (n=152) required, leading to unidentifiable model parameters. Can I do anything about this? Or do I just have to few subjects? Also, is (1 | subject) alone appropriate?
library(ANCOMBC)
library(phyloseq)

# Assuming 'tse' is a properly prepared TreeSummarizedExperiment object from a phyloseq object
ancombc2_BMI_cat_results <- ancombc2(
  data = tse,                                     # your phyloseq object
  assay_name = "counts",                          # count table name
  tax_level = "phylum",                           # taxonomic level for analysis
  fix_formula = "TRIBMI",                         # fixed effects, adjusted for interaction
  rand_formula = "(1 | subject)",                 # random effects, one intercept per subject
  p_adj_method = "holm",                          # p-value adjustment method
  prv_cut = 0.10,                                 # prevalence cut-off for taxa
  lib_cut = 1000,                                 # library size cut-off
  s0_perc = 0.05,                                 # small constant in denominator
  group = "BMI",                                  # grouping variable for comparisons
  struc_zero = TRUE,                              # enabling detection of structural zeros
  neg_lb = TRUE,                                  # using lower bound for zero detection
  alpha = 0.05,                                   # significance level
  n_cl = 1,                                       # number of clusters for parallel processing
  verbose = TRUE,                                 # verbose output for more information
  global = TRUE,                                  # perform a global test
  pairwise = TRUE,                                # perform pairwise comparisons
  trend = FALSE,                                  # enable/disable trend tests
  iter_control = list(tol = 1e-2, max_iter = 20, verbose = TRUE),  # iteration control
  em_control = list(tol = 1e-5, max_iter = 100),  # E-M algorithm control
  lme_control = lme4::lmerControl()               # control for mixed model fitting
)

Curent Model Performance:
During the REML iterations, the model struggled to find an optimum (?), showing significant fluctuation in epsilon values across 20 iterations. I think this suggests possible issues with model convergence or fit. How do I adress this? Increase number of iterations (and pray)?
Questions:

Is the configuration of fixed effects (TRIBMI) and random effects
((1 | subject)) appropriate for my research question focusing on
interactions between trimesters and BMI categories? (Or is there maybe a better way include the interaction between Trimester and BMI that takes the order of Trimesters into account? I thought about splitting the data and analysing the Trimesters in isolation)

How should the group = variable be set in ANCOM-BC to align best
with the research question about differential abundance across BMI
categories and trimesters? I am looking for feedback on whether this
model setup is robust and appropriate for capturing complex
interactions in my dataset, or if there are alternative strategies I
should consider.


Thank you for any insights or suggestions you can provide!

BMI is a continuous index. What's the point in categorizing a pregnant woman as either "lean" or "obese"? How did you decide that?

It is just conform the standard in the field. See, for examples, the link I put in the question: they all treat BMI as a categorical variable

Is "obese" based on BMI prior to pregnancy? Also, you might benefit from treating BMI as continuous, as @dipetkov indicates. See Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies online text or the extensive discussion on this page. Sometimes the standard in the field needs to be improved. You could fit a proper continuous model and then illustrate model results with BMI values considered "lean" or "obese."

Model Configuration and Random Effects:
The main challenge you're facing with the (Trimester | subject) model stems from the complexity and number of parameters relative to your sample size. As you've observed, trying to fit a model with more random effects parameters (152) than available data points (68) results in unidentifiable model parameters. You might address this by simplifying the random structure by using (1 | subject) is a practical approach when the data does not support more complex random effects structures. This simpler model imposes a single random intercept per subject, which accounts for the inter-subject variability while being less demanding on the data.
If the model is still not converging, try adjusting the lme_control parameters in lmerControl(). Increasing the maximum number of iterations or adjusting the optimiser's settings might help achieve convergence.
Regarding your questions on setting up the ANCOM-BC (Analysis of Composition of Microbiomes with Bias Correction) analysis:
Fixed and Random Effects Configuration: The fixed effects configuration (TRIBMI) is appropriate if you're interested in the interaction between BMI and trimesters. However, considering the ordered nature of trimesters and BMI categories, you might explore models that can account for this ordering explicitly, potentially using continuous and not categorised data.

Is the configuration of fixed effects (TRIBMI) and random effects ((1 | subject)) appropriate for my research question focusing on interactions between trimesters and BMI categories? (Or is there maybe a better way include the interaction between Trimester and BMI that takes the order of Trimesters into account? I thought about splitting the data and analysing the Trimesters in isolation)

Analysing the disagregated data would lead to a big loss in statistical power and I wouldn't recommend if. It would, of course, be more better if you worked with BMI (and possibly trimester) as continuous numeric variables, in which case there would be no problem with trimester or bmi  being inherently ordinal as it stands at the moment. If you used continuous/numeric data this will also allow you to explore non-linearity quite easily.
I saw the comments in the OP about this:

BMI is a continuous index. What's the point in categorizing a pregnant woman as either "lean" or "obese"? How did you decide that? – dipetkov commented Jun 21 at 14:31


It is just conform the standard in the field. See, for examples, the link I put in the question: they all treat BMI as a categorical variable – DeMelkbroer Commented Jun 21 at 14:4**

As you see, @dipetkov has the same concern. Your response about it being the standard in the field, I'm sorry to say, does not hold water with me,

How should the group = variable be set in ANCOM-BC to align best with the research question about differential abundance across BMI categories and trimesters? I am looking for feedback on whether this model setup is robust and appropriate for capturing complex interactions in my dataset, or if there are alternative strategies I should consider.

In ANCOM-BC, the group argument plays an important role in how the analysis handles comparisons and adjustments for compositional differences across groups within your dataset. This argument specifies which variable in your dataset should be used to define the groups for which differential abundance analysis will be conducted.
The model can perform pairwise comparisons of microbiota abuIn your case, the group variable is set to "BMI" and BMI has two categories, "Lean" and "Obese", the model will test for differences in microbiota abundance between these two BMI categories.
The choice of group also helps control and adjust for compositional differences and potential confounders in the analysis. By focusing on this variable, the analysis aims to elucidate the impact of this specific factor (such as BMI) on microbiota composition, while controlling for other variables as specified in the model formula.
Setting aside the problems caused by categorising continuous numeric variables (BMI and trimester in this case), discussed above, since your primary interest is in the interaction effects across different BMI categories and trimesters, setting group = "TRIBMI" might be more aligned with your research question. This setting would help you look at differential abundance specific to each combination of BMI category and trimester.
